# Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, primeng

in using below versions of angular:

### there  is  a  build  script  to  build  and I run  npm  run  build  to  run  this  project  but I am  getting  an  error  after  changed  my  laptop   and  newly installed nodjs angular

```
  / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.1
Node: 12.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.1
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.1
@schematics/angular          9.0.1
@schematics/update           0.900.1
```

### rxjs                         6.5.3

may package json is

```
{
  "name": "webprimeng",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-path ../src/main/resources/static --base-href /transaction/ --deploy-url /transaction/",
    "watch": "ng build --prod --output-path ../src/main/resources/static --base-href /transaction/ --deploy-url /transaction/ --watch",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^7.4.2",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-web-storage": "^4.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.12",
    "primeflex": "^1.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^6.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

---

my error is  :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'
Require stack:
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\index.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build-impl.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- D:\workspace\webprimeng\primeng\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\yyy~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-hLuf5T\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! webprimeng@0.0.0 build: `ng build --prod --output-path ../src/main/resources/static --base-href /transaction/ --deploy-url /transaction/`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webprimeng@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yyyy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-09T14_34_11_713Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a version mismatch between your project and the devDependency. You might have probably used npm audit fix --force or a similar auto update command, which might have updated the devDependencies in "package.json" file.

Comment: so what should i do to avoid this issue?

Comment: i'm new to angular please help me to avoid this issue